# Mongoose validation error when using custom validator

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Following is the Schema which is not working correctly with custom validator-

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email : { type: String, validate: lengthValidator },
});

// Length validator for email
var lengthValidator  = function(val){
    if(val && val.length >= 6  )
        return true;
    return false;
};

var User = mongoose.model('User',userSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

Error -

```
Error: Invalid validator. Received (undefined) undefined. See http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schematype_SchemaType-validate
    at SchemaString.SchemaType.validate (/MY_PROJECT_PATH/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:416:13)
    at SchemaString.SchemaType (/MY_PROJECT_PATH/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:38:13)
    at new SchemaString (/MY_PROJECT_PATH/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema/string.js:24:14)
    at Function.Schema.interpretAsType (/MY_PROJECT_PATH/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema.js:367:10)
    at Schema.path (/MY_PROJECT_PATH/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema.js:305:29)
    at Schema.add (/MY_PROJECT_PATH/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema.js:217:12)
    at new Schema (/MY_PROJECT_PATH/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema.js:73:10)
    at Object.&lt;anonymous&gt; (/MY_PROJECT_PATH/models/users.js:2:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
```

However if I remove `validate` then it is working correctly as I checked by changing the type from `String` to `Number`.

Let me know what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue you're experiencing is related to hoisting. The way that you've written your validation function means that at the time you're passing it into the schema it's an undefined value; it's not until afterwards that the variable gets set.

Here's a really basic example of the problem.

```
var thing = {
    foo: bar
}

var bar = function () {
    alert('hello!');
}

thing.foo();
```

When `thing.foo()` is called, it will throw an error. Why? Because this is how JavaScript interprets what I wrote:

```
var bar;

var thing = {
    foo: bar // At this point, bar is undefined
}

bar = function () {
    alert('hello!');
}

thing.foo();
```

The same thing is happening to your code. When you set the validate property in the schema to `lengthValidate`, it hasn't been defined yet.

There's two ways to fix it.

1. Move the validation function definition above the schema definition in the code.
2. Use `function lengthValidator(val)` instead of `var lengthValidator = function(val)`

Comment: @matthewwtole I am not getting any error but also it is not validating too ..This is the method but I am getting only "try" even my email length is 2 http://codepad.org/a3Ld6yFR

Comment: You can't do multiple calls to `res.send`, the first one will end the response.

Comment: @matthewwtole now I am getting a blank array `[]` after i commented `res.send('try');`

Comment: Well that's probably because you're getting no results.

Comment: Yes but I suppose it should validate first before sending to the db..because then only the Schema validations seems to be relevant i.e I should get a response of `Wrong` in the error

Comment: Validation has nothing to do with finding documents, only saving them.

Comment: @matthewwtole thx for making the concept clear +1 and a green tick :)